# Javascript not recognizing self.function when inside onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, self

I have a Javascript file that I added to. It's for a twitter plugin, and I'm adding a filter function.

This is my script (the relevant parts):

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var pluginName = "twitterFeed",
        defaults = {
            username: null,
            webservice_url: "/services/Scope/Country_United_States_Internet/TwitterService.svc/DoTwitterSearch",
            num_tweets: 3
        };    

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;

        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function() {
        //if username is unknown 
            if(this.options.username == null) {
                // do nothing
                try{console.log('twitter username not found')}catch(err){};
                return false;
            }
            // Get the tweets to display
            this.getTweets();

            $(".twitter-search input").on("change", function () {
                var filters = this.formatFilters($(this).val());
                this.getTweets(filters);
            });
        },

        formatFilters : function(filterString) {
            var hashtags = filterString.split(" ");
            var hashtagString = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < hashtags.length; i++) {
                var hashtag = hashtags[i];
                hashtag = hashtag.replace(",", "");
                if (hashtag[0] !== "#") {
                    hashtag = "#" + hashtag;
                }
                hashtagString += " " + hashtag;
            }
            return hashtagString;
        },

        getTweets : function(filters){
            var self = this;
            var query = "from:" + self.options.username;
            if (filters) {
                query += filters;
            }
            var post_data = JSON.stringify(
                {
                    "PageSize" : self.options.num_tweets,
                    "TwitterQuery" : query
                }
            );
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  // Change to POST for development environment
                url: this.options.webservice_url,
                data: post_data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                timeout:2000,
                success: function(data) { 
                    // render the tweets
                    self.renderTweets(data.ContentItems);
                },
                error: function(error, type){
                    try{console.log(type);}catch(err){}
                }
            });
        },
```

I added the `$(".twitter-search input")` on change event (in `init`) and I added the `formatFilters()` function. However, in the onchange function, I get the error "this.formatFilters() is not defined". I tried removed `this` but still got "formatFilters() is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `this` inside of an event handler means whatever HTML element the event was activated on.

Instead, you need to keep track of the actual `Plugin` object, not the HTML element.

```
var self = this;
$(".twitter-search input").on("change", function () {
    var filters = self.formatFilters($(this).val());
    self.getTweets(filters);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is with function scope. When you refer to this in the event handler it points to the callback scope and not the scope of your *formatFilters* function.

To fix it - In the `init` function add `var self = this;` on the first line and then change the call to use `self.formatFilters` instead of `this.formatFilters`